# Nested NSManagedObjectContext for core data, how to share and manage data properly?

Tags: multithreading, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext, moc

This is the first post in stackoverflow for me. Because I encountered the problem that I can't solve even by looking up in google and documents.

I get a small iOS project, which is a weather searching app. Basically it is easy to implement overall, but there are some rules I have to follow:

One parent context on a background thread which is linked to the persistent store (on disk);
one child context on the main thread for the UI;
one child context on a background thread for talking to the web service.

After seeing this, I found an image online:
[image]

This image shows what exactly should do for this project. And I get few problems right now.

1. As image shows, I use `[[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSMainQueueConcurrencyType]` to define my main UI MOC, and use NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType to define my webMOC and diskMOC. Question is that, shall I put everything into [UIMOC performBlock: ^{......}] ?
2. I am quite confused right now, isn't UI runs on main thread? so what is the point of NSMainQueueConcurrencyType?
3. After reading lot of documents, I found that the way to share data between childMOC and parentMOC are either make childMOC run "save" function, or call merge function through notification.
   (a) for the first one, do I need to [childMOC save] then do [parentMOC save]? or after [childMOC save], parentMOC automatically get updated?
   (b) I am not sure which way is more appropriate.
4. The image above have 3 levels MOC. If I do "save" function at the lowest level MOC and can highest level MOC get data shared?
5. As what I thought about, why couln't the lowest level MOC combined with highest level MOC and to read and write? meantime, the UIMOC in the middle, do I have to put it into performBlock function of Context to run NSFetchedResultController?